Gallery of moving GIF thumbnails
Question:
How can I view a folder of animated GIFs as a gallery of animated thumbnails?
Preferably with support for drag and drop to save the interesting ones.

Context:
I have a process that generates thousands of GIFs, each a few seconds long, and I need to quickly identify the ones that look the best for my purposes. This selection process is significantly faster if I can look at a grid of playing GIFs instead of looking at them one by one.
I am aware that this could be a heavy operation when having many files, but I am prepared to pay that price to be able to quickly skim through a lot of GIFs.

The paid version of the image viewer Pictureflect is able to play GIFs in the thumbnail view, and offers a free trial.
